# Add img on top of img html

Tags: html, css, positioning

I have two img tags as shown below, but the img tag with the class `portfolioImage1` always shows up underneath the img tag with the class `portfolioItem1`. How can I achieve having it the other way around so that `portfolioImage1` is above `portfolioItem1`?

```
<div class="portfolioContainer">
    <img class="portfolioImage1" src="img/image1.png" />
    <img class="portfolioItem1" src="img/portfolioItem.png" />
</div>
```

CSS

```
.portfolioContainer {
    height: 400px;
    width: 490px;
    left: 400px;
    top: 275px;
    position: absolute;
}
.portfolioItem1 {
    left: 20px;
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute; 
}
.portfolioImage1 {
    z-index: 2;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT:

You need to add a position relative, absolute or fixed to the portfolioImage1 in order for z-index to work.

OLD:

If you mean behind the image try using z-index:

```
<div class="portfolioContainer" style="position: relative;"> 
    <img class="portfolioImage1" src="img/image1.png" style="position: relative; z-index: 2" /> 
    <img class="portfolioItem1" src="img/portfolioItem.png" style="position: relative; z-index: 1" /> 
</div>
```

If you mean below, you can use absolute or relative positioning, but we need dimensions and desired results. For example, say that image1.png is 20px high and portfolioItem.png is 25px high:

```
<div class="portfolioContainer"> 
    <img class="portfolioImage1" src="img/image1.png" style="position: relative; top: 25px;" /> 
    <img class="portfolioItem1" src="img/portfolioItem.png" style="position: relative; top -20px" /> 
</div>
```